# Grafana dashboard not showing data (on EKS)

Tags: grafana, prometheus, amazon-eks

I have deployed Prometheus-Grafana on kubernetes cluster with following manifest file :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: grafana
  namespace: kube-monitoring
  labels:
    app: grafana
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: grafana
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: grafana
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: grafana
        image: grafana/grafana:6.3.2
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
          - name: GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER
            value: admin
          - name: GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: grafana-secret
                key: admin-password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 2500Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
              - wget
              - localhost:3000
              - --spider
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 30
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/grafana
          subPath: grafana
          name: grafana-storage
          readOnly: false
        - mountPath: /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/
          name: grafana-datasource-conf
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/
          name: grafana-dashboards-conf
          readOnly: false
        - mountPath: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/0/k8s-cluster-usage
          name: grafana-dashboard-k8s-cluster-usage
          readOnly: false
        - mountPath: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/0/k8s-cluster-nodes
          name: grafana-dashboard-k8s-cluster-nodes
          readOnly: false
        - mountPath: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/0/k8s-core-dns
          name: grafana-dashboard-k8s-core-dns
          readOnly: false
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 472
        fsGroup: 472
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: grafana-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pvc-grafana
      - name: grafana-datasource-conf
        configMap:
          name: grafana-datasource-conf
          items:
            - key: datasource.yaml
              path: datasource.yaml
      - name: grafana-dashboards-conf
        configMap:
          name: grafana-dashboards-conf
          items:
            - key: dashboards.yaml
              path: dashboards.yaml
      - name: grafana-dashboard-k8s-cluster-usage
        configMap:
          name: grafana-dashboard-k8s-cluster-usage
      - name: grafana-dashboard-k8s-cluster-nodes
        configMap:
          name: grafana-dashboard-k8s-cluster-nodes
      - name: grafana-dashboard-k8s-core-dns
        configMap:
          name: grafana-dashboard-k8s-core-dns
```

and dashboard config is https://pastebin.com/zAYn9BhY (its too long)

Among the list `Core DNS` & `Cluster Usages` shows proper data & graphs, but `Cluster Nodes` doesn't show any data all metric says `No data points`

Anyone can help here ?

Answer (score 2):

`Cluster Nodes` won't show you any metrics, because you are probably missing [metric-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server).

If you are staring with whole Prometheus stack I would consider using [prometheus-operator](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator) deployed via helm. It is a little overwhelming, but in a fairly easy way, you can start with it and prometheus-operator will deploy metrics-server too.

Comment: I have installed metric-server in `kube-system` namespace.

Comment: If so check the `Service Discovery` tab in your Prometheus GUI and find if is scraping metrics.